# regex for extracting anchor in a url

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract an anchor tag and everything behind it from a url using preg_replace. I found one to remove everything after the #, but I want one that removes the # and everything behind it.

http://blah.com#removethis

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: A regular expression here seems like overkill.  Why not just `explode('#','http://blah.com#removethis',2)[0]`?

Comment: @kerkeslager That code won't work in PHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
$url = "http://blah.com#removethis";
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

> fragment - after the hashmark #

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => blah.com
    [fragment] => removethis
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way without regex:

```
$newurl = substr($url, 0, strpos($url,"#"));
```

Comment: @Russell Dias,isn't it what OP wanted?

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = preg_replace('/#.*$/', '', $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = preg_replace('@#.*$@', '', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regexes when there are proper library functions to do the job.

Comment: While I agree wholeheartedly with the sentiment, this isn't really an answer.